# BAT script search for a particular type of file and execute a command

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, file-search

I want to search a particular file type(.plt) and then I want to execute a command line command(Eg. Change file type). I am working in windows 7.

Can I write a .bat script to do this issue?

Please help me.....please give me some example.....

Comment: bash is the unix shell scripting language :P

Comment: Thanks for your correction...

Comment: Please give some example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for /r %i IN (*.plt) DO echo %i`

will list all of the .plt files in the current directory and sub-directories, replace echo with the command of your choice

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean. Could this be it?

`ren *.plt *.foo`

If you must have a batch file, I once wrote a script.

http://www.adarshr.com/papers/renamex

Answer (score 0):

As an update to the highest answer, you should use double percent signs (%%) for the varibles in a for command within a batch file now (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for).

```
for %%i IN (*.txt) DO echo %%i
```